# Por que preciso chamar Schema::table, no Laravel, mais de uma vez?

Tags: php, laravel

No momento, estou em um curso da Udemy sobre Laravel 7. Em um ponto dele, preciso renomear a coluna de uma tabela chamada **site_contacts**. Quando tento simplificar o código e colocar todas as instruções em apenas um callback ocorrerá o erro `There is no column with name 'contact_reason_id' on table 'site_contacts'` ao chegar na instrução para alterar o tipo da coluna. Porém, se eu colocar separadamente, como está no código, a migration é executada sem problemas.

Gostaria apenas de entender porque precisa ser feita desta forma e se tem algum jeito melhor. A princípio, acho que a classe precisa atualizar seus atributos internos para prosseguir com as instruções. É isso mesmo o que ocorre?

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('site_contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->renameColumn('contact_reason', 'contact_reason_id');
    });

    Schema::table('site_contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('contact_reason_id')->change();
    });

    Schema::table('site_contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('contact_reason_id')->references('id')->on('contact_reasons');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('site_contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('site_contacts_contact_reason_id_foreign');
        $table->dropIndex('site_contacts_contact_reason_id_foreign');
    });

    Schema::table('site_contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('contact_reason_id')->change();
    });

    Schema::table('site_contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->renameColumn('contact_reason_id', 'contact_reason');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já passei por isso, ao que parece, o "rename" da coluna: 'contact_reason' para 'contact_reason_id' só ocorre quando toda a migração é executada.

Ocorre o erro que está enfrentando porque quando ele chega no trecho:

```
 Schema::table('site_contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('contact_reason_id')->change();
});
```

a coluna 'contact_reason_id' ainda não existe.

Acho interessante querer saber o porque, mas o ideal é você fazer separadamente mesmo.